# <img> Hover on general siblings is not working

Tags: html, css, hover, siblings

Hover on the displayed image inside `<div class="like absolute">` wouldn't displays the image inside `<div class="balloons absolute">`.

```
<div id="container" class="relative">
    <div class="like absolute">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.simplemailerresponsive.bugs3.com/images/like.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Like" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="balloons absolute">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.simplemailerresponsive.bugs3.com/images/love_symbol.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Symbol" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code `div#container` is the parent `<div>`
"like" and "balloons" are the siblings of each other.

CSS:

```
#container .like a img:hover ~ .balloons > a > img{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/psut1e3b/)

Comment: `img` has no siblings, you can't use a sibling selector to traverse back up the DOM.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what "sibling" means.

Comment: Thank You Alexander, so that i gave sibling to the "container", please modify the css and post the link.

Comment: Hi Bolt, I am confused but now i got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
.like{
opacity: 0;
border: none;}
```

Fixed, Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/psut1e3b/17/

If you hover over the like hand, the heart appears. You can play with the various classes/positioning to get your desired result.

Comment: Thank you Kyle Booth, i want if hover on hand image then heart image will be appear, i need like this, please solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like button is always visible. On Hover: the balloons is shown. That's it.
I am not sure if this is what you are looking for: Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3ddzzeqe/)

CSS:

```
.balloons{
    display:none;
}

.like:hover + .balloons{
    display:block;
}
```